# Count consecutive ocurrences SQL - PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to count the number of consecutive weeks an employee went to work. So I have this table that has whether jon or andy went to work on certain weeks (I have all week of the year).

I am trying on Postgresql

[image: Input table]

What I would like know the number of times each person went consecutively to work x number of weeks.

So the way the below is read is that Andy went twice two consecutive weeks.

[image: Output Table]

I feel like I am close. On python I could use a for loop probably, but on Postgresql I am a bit lost.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add the SQL you currently have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We group each amount of consecutive weeks worked per person and then group by the result and the person.

```
select    person
         ,consecutive_weeks
         ,count(*)/consecutive_weeks as times
from      (
          select    person
                   ,sum(case when "went to work?" = 1 then 1 end) over(partition by person, grp) as consecutive_weeks
          from     (
                   select  *
                           ,count(mrk) over(partition by person order by week) as grp
                   from    (
                           select  *
                                   ,case when "went to work?" <> lag("went to work?") over(partition by person order by week) then 1 end as mrk
                           from    t
                           ) t
                  ) t
         ) t
where    consecutive_weeks is not null
group by person, consecutive_weeks
order by person
```

| person | consecutive_weeks | times |
| --- | --- | --- |
| andy | 2 | 2 |
| john | 3 | 1 |
| john | 2 | 1 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Bjq98e4a)

Comment: This logic seems to be correct but I get this error, not sure why.
ERROR: Aggregate window functions with an ORDER BY clause require a frame clause

Comment: I  try this query and work fine.

Comment: @Johnny try and play with the fiddle I posted. I'm guessing you copied something wrong. Also try to take the order by clause out and see what you get.

Comment: In fiddle works fine, but when I try in my database (Redshift), I get that error. If I remove the order by clause, I get this, which is wrong

person consecutive_weeks times
andy         4                         1
john        5                         1

Comment: @Johnny you asked about postgres and that's what I answered. Please vote up and accept the answer. If you have a question about redshift please post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can find groups of weeks where a person was present, assigning a running `id` to each row of the group, and then apply a `count` on the results, performing a `group by` on the `id`:

```
with cte as (
   select t3.person, t3.k, count(*) c from 
      (select t.*, (select sum((t1.person = t.person and t1.week <= t.week and t1.at_work = 0)::int) k from tbl t1) 
       from tbl t) t3 
   where t3.at_work != 0 group by t3.person, t3.k
)
select c.person, c.c, count(*) c1 from cte c group by c.person, c.c order by c1
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_RG1GKIo).